# sbt: cross-publish from build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

Currently, I'm using SBT scripted plugin for testing. To publish a plugin into the local repository, following code snippet in build.sbt is used:

```
crossScalaVersions := Seq(scalaVersion.value,"2.11.7")

scriptedDependencies := {
      val local = publishLocal.value
}
```

This way the artefact gets published into the local repository, but only for the version `scalaVersion.value`. I would like to have it cross-published for both scala versions. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you use `+publishLocal`, with the `+` ? That should do it. Also, I would advise against referring to `scalaVersion` in the definition of `crossScalaVersions`. That's asking for trouble. Explicitly write `"2.10.6"` or what you want there.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But the question is about build.sbt, not a command line. There is a `TaskKey publishLocal` and the `+` is provided by  the sbt interpreter. You could check for example by typing `help +` in sbt console

Comment: `scriptedDependencies` is not meant to be used like this. `sbt` is *meant* to be called either interactively, or with one or more commands on the command line. That's where you would write `+publishLocal`. For example `$ sbt +publishLocal`

Comment: I think it's a valid question. No matter *why* the author of the question wanted to do that the answer would be useful. I don't buy `sbt` "is meant to to be called interactively" argument because it also provides you the API and means to write your own tasks. And in your own custom tasks you may need to e.g. cross publish a few modules in programmatic way. I am in such need now

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in the comments by @srjd you can use the `+` prefix.

As mentioned in this [section of the docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Combined+Pages.html#Cross+building+a+project+statefully)

> To build against all versions listed in crossScalaVersions, prefix the action to run with +. For example:

```
> + test
```

> A typical way to use this feature is to do development on a single Scala version (no + prefix) and then cross-build (using +) occasionally and when releasing.

This works for any action, including `publisLocal`.

```
> + publishLocal
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. As mentioned earlier, the question is about build.sbt, not a command line. There is a TaskKey publishLocal and the + is provided by the sbt interpreter. You could check for example by typing help + in sbt console